# Passing context to a Handlebars partial

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, handlebars.js

I wish to pass the parent templates context to a handlebars partial.

I register my partial in app.js with the following

```
Handlebars.registerPartial("lifestyles", Handlebars.templates['partials/product-lifestyles']());
```

I then render my partial inside my main template file like the following, passing in this as a second parameters of which I understand it *should* pass in the context of the parent

```
{>lifestyles this}}
```

I have a log helper which console logs a parameter, inside my partial I log out this, it returns undefined.

```
{{log this}}
```

Evidentially my context isn't being passed into my partial.

My understanding is that Handlebars supports this functionality, so what could be the reason it is not functioning?

Comment: your partial is missing a left {. Is that a bug or just a mistype?

Comment: also showing what the parent template looks like might also provide some incite.

Answer (score 4):

STHayden is right, You need two opening braces when you call a partial

```
{{>lifestyles this}}
```

This is an example of using partial templates

http://jsfiddle.net/UMBGC/16/